# How to avoid "E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'MyMethodName'" when using open array parameters?

Tags: delphi, overloading, delphi-2007, open-array-parameters

Sometimes I get *"E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'MyMethodName'"* when passing open arrays to overloaded methods.

Example:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Test(AArrA : array of integer); overload;
    procedure Test(AArrA : array of TObject); overload;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test([10, 15]);
end;
```

It produces the following error:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(37): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'Test'

Until now, I've always used a temporary dynamic array due to avoid the error but I don't find it very clean

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Tmp : array of integer;
begin
  SetLength(Tmp, 2);
  Tmp[0] := 10;
  Tmp[1] := 15;

  Test(Tmp);
end;
```

Is there a cleaner way to help Delphi discerning between overloads which accepts open array parameters?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  The code shown compiles and executes properly in modern versions of the compiler.  It must be a bug in D2007 that was already fixed in a later version.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Happy to know that it is no more a problem in newer versions. Anyhow, is there any workaround for Delphi2007?

Comment: The only workaround is the one you already found - use a local variable for the array. You don't have to use a dynamic array, though. You can use a static array instead: `var Tmp : array[0..1] of integer; Tmp[0] := 10; Tmp[1] := 15; Test(Tmp);`